# How do I compile multiple SCSS files in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

I have separate SCSS files I want to compile into separate CSS files. Here is a part of my Webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/js/main.js', './src/scss/main.scss', './src/scss/additional.scss'],
  output: {
    filename: './assets/js/main.bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: './assets/css/main.bundle.css',
    }),
  ],
  modules: {...}
}
```

The example above will only compile `main.scss` and omit `additional.scss`. Here is what I tried:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ['./src/js/main.js', './src/scss/main.scss'],
    additional: './src/scss/additional.scss',
  },
  output: {
    filename: './assets/js/[name].bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: './assets/css/[name].bundle.css',
    }),
  ],
  modules: {...}
}
```

This kinda works, however this will also generate an `additional.bundle.js` which I don't need (I only need one JavaScript output and two CSS files). Any ideas?

Comment: I think that you've got a wrong impression of webpack, it is not a task runner, but a bundler.

Comment: @felixmosh agree, however sometimes you'd want to keep your css in separate files and bundle js files only.

Comment: It is not related, webpack as a bundler, works on an entry point, and loads css & js & images. then u can define what to do with it, either be bundled in the js file or emit it into a separate file.

Comment: So I guess my question was how to remove/disable a JS output for an entry. I had to remove it as I posted in my answer below, while ideally I wouldn't have it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I can up with. You basically need to create separate config objects for scss and everything else:

```
module.exports = [{
  entry: {
    main: ['./src/js/main.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: './assets/js/[name].bundle.js',
  },
  modules: {...}
}, {
  entry: {
    main: ['./src/scss/main.scss'],
    additional: ['./src/scss/additional.scss'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: './.leftover/[name].bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: './assets/css/[name].bundle.css',
    }),
  ],
  modules: {...}
}]
```

then remove the `.leftover` directory on `npm run build`.

`package.json`:

```
"build": "webpack --mode production && del-cli dist/.leftover"
```

Not the cleanest solution, however that's the only one I can think of.